# FindShortestTour suddenly runs far slower for large numbers of points

Tags: performance-tuning, timing

I was doing a benchmark of FindShortestTour and I noticed something really weird. Around 10000 points, FindShortestTour suddenly takes 6 times as long without explanation:

```
times = Table[
    pts = RandomSample[
        Tuples[Range[n], 2] + RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, {n^2, 2}]];
    {Length@pts, AbsoluteTiming[FindShortestTour[pts];][[1]]}, 
    {n, 128}];
ListLinePlot[times]
```

Output: (time is measured in seconds along the y axis)

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: I can confirm the behavior on Mathematica 11.0.1. for macos. Mathematica seems to switch to another optimization method for more than 10000 points.

Comment: How can I prevent this switch?

Comment: Just a guess, but it might have to do with internals for how the set of pairwise distances is generated. There could be a threshold below which it is a dense matrix, and above which the performance deteriorates (but you avoid swap Hades due to the memory requirements of that matrix).